# Unit Test KafkaMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

Is it possible to unit test the `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` @Bean? I want to know if it is possible to conduct a put unit test on the code I use to construct the container. I'm trying to make sure that the container is getting built successfully.

However when I directly unit test the function that does this with a fake set of consumer Properties, I get an error that says

`Failed to Construct Kafka Consumer.... No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers`

This error leads me to believe that this may not be possible to test in this manner. Is there another way to test this or is there a way to actually build the kafka message listener container and verify it with a unit test?

Comment: It's not clear what behavior exactly you want to test. It's a framework class, so it's assume it's already unit tested, you're talking about an integration test, in which case you just send the message you need and verify it gets handled. There's not much more specifics you can expect from the info you give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is attempting to start but it doesn't have configuration about which broker(s) to talk to (because of your dummy properties).

You can set its `autoStartup` property to `false` to prevent Spring from `start()`ing it.

You can use a property placeholder so the value is true for production and false for this test.